# Query custom taxonomy by term id?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, wp-query, url-rewriting

I made a custom post type and a custom taxonomy, but I have a problem.

When I access the url `http://www.ithemes.co.kr/?shopcat=galaxy-s`, it works well. But when I access the url `http://www.ithemes.co.kr/?shopcat=5`, it returns a 404 page. `galaxy-s` is the taxonomy term slug, but I want to access it by `term_id`, like you can with a category: `cat=1`. I prefer `cat=1`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by default, but you can convert the numeric terms back to slugs with the `pre_get_posts` hook. I tested this with WP 3.0.1, but in 3.1 the taxonomy query handling changed, so I don't know whether this will work by default or if there is a better way to do it.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse6066_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse6066_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_tax ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $wp_query->get( 'term' ) ) ) {
            // Convert numberic terms to term slugs
            $term = get_term_by( 'term_id', $wp_query->get( 'term' ), $wp_query->get( 'taxonomy' ) );
            if ( $term ) {
                $wp_query->set( 'term', $term->slug );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bizarre that you prefer the numeric version, many would choose the term slug for SEO reasons.

Comment: Wow, it's too work!!!!
you save my time:)
so thank you^^

Comment: @Ssong Won: You can [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this way others can see it is solved for you. It also gives your and my "reputation score" a boost. I'm happy it works for you, and I hope to see other good questions and answers from you on this site!

Answer (score 0):

These few lines are very useful for `wp_dropdown_categories` used in custom taxonomies for backend (edit.php) list subselection.  Because values in list are `term id` and not usable as is for sub selection in query. The parts of code below were used in a class managing custom post type and custom taxonomy.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array(&$this,'restrict_manage_writer_posts') );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array(&$this,'wpse6066_pre_get_posts' ) );

function restrict_manage_writer_posts () {

        $selected = "";
        if ( isset ( $_GET['writer_name'] )  ) { 
            $selected = $_GET['writer_name'];
        }
        $dropdown_options = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'writer',
                    'show_option_all' => __( 'View all writers' ),
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'hierarchical' => 1,
                    'show_count' => 0,
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'name' => 'writer_name',
                    'selected' => $selected
                );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_options );

    }
    /** 
     * to fixes wp_dropdown_categories id value in option
     * thanks to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/query-custom-taxonomy-by-term-id 
     */
    function wpse6066_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
    {
        if ( $wp_query->is_tax ) {  ;
            if ( is_numeric( $wp_query->get( 'writer_name' ) ) ) {
                // Convert numberic terms to term slugs for dropdown

                $term = get_term_by( 'term_id', $wp_query->get( 'writer_name' ), 'writer' );

                if ( $term ) {
                    $wp_query->set( 'writer_name', $term->slug );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```